"This answer was migrated to another site 19 mins ago along with its parent question" but the answer timeline doesn't show that. What's going on?
I read on this deleted answer (screenshot):

This answer is hidden. This answer was migrated to another site 19 mins ago along with its parent question.

However, the answer timeline (screenshot) doesn't show any migration in the past 1 hour. A migration did happen but this was over 24 hours ago. What's going on? I don't know if that's a bug or if missed something.

This sounds like a bug. The reasons shown for deletion are often not stored in the deletion record itself, but synthesized from a combination of evidence on the post, its history, its parent's history, etc. There have been... and clearly currently remain... scenarios where this logic short-circuits in the presence of certain records even when they do not make sense. In this case, I'm guessing the logic looks at "migrationDate" but doesn't check the post history for the migration direction. I'm gonna guess this bug was introduced when fixing an even more ridiculous bug

Adding to Shog's likely correct analysis, looks like the logic is as following: in case of migrated question, and a deleted answer, the system assumes the migration caused the deletion. This can, of course, be wrong, e.g. when the answer is deleted by other means.
